# How to draw hand drawn style icons?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, icon, illustration

[image: hand drawn image]

I have always wondered how illustrations like above are drawn. What is the usual and efficient way? Do designers do sketches first and then trace over them or there is a technique?

It looks specially crafted to look hand drawn, but still is clear in its function. This style is most used in videos describing some new website etc.

I would like to produce this either using Photoshop or Illustrator and I can use a graphic tablet.

Comment: You answered your own question. These were hand drawn.

Comment: so these are? hand drawn.....but in animations i have seen lines animate what about that...or just move cartoonishly.

Comment: possible duplicate, but a lot could be said regarding using a tablet, using textured brushes, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a video explaining the processes:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2y9GlmOPT2w

Believe it or not.. people actually can draw.

So often people assume there's some computer trick to something magical they can do to mimic skill as an artist when the answer is really... be an artist who can draw or hire one.

If you just want hand-drawn style icons, draw them and then scan them. I have yet to find any digital processes which yields better results. Even with a tablet and Photoshop the drawing isn't the same. If you have a Cintique then you may be able to forego scanning, but the distance and angle of tablet use seems to not be conducive to traditional results on paper.

Comment: +1 for "Believe it or not.. people actually can draw. So often people assume there's some computer trick to something magical they can do to mimic skill as an artist when the answer is really... be an artist who can draw or hire one." An often overlooked point..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are asking about the computer in your example or the logos.

**The computer:**

A lot of drawings like these are made by drawing over a picture or using `trace option` in illustrator.

- Take an image into illustrator and play with trace.
- Or, take it into illustrator, make a new layer, lock the layer with
  the image, and trace by hand the lines you need.

This process would be easiest if you have made the image black and white with high contrast in photoshop first. [Here is a post explaining these approaches.](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/1360/convert-a-line-drawing-from-raster-to-vector/1371#1371)

**The logos:**

Generally, the most efficient way is to sketch lots of ideas on paper. And in the case of LinkedIn and Facebook, slight alteration of an existing font (this usually done in illustrator by writing text - > create outline - > ungroup - > alter the vector bezier points to your hearts content).

**Animation:**

Using some kind of animation programme (such as flash, Blender, GoAnimate, AnimeStudio, or a bunch of others, depending on your preferences and what the end goal is).